# regex para validar nome completo com limite de caracteres

Tags: javascript, regex

Quero uma regex que aceite somente letras (maiúsculas ou minúsculas), podendo conter espaço, e tenha um mínimo de 3 letras e máximo 20 letras. Elaborei o código abaixo e está funcionando para o tipo de texto que quero receber, inclusive para o mínimo de letras, porém não está restringindo ao máximo de 20 letras. Conseguem me ajudar?

```
/([A-Za-z]\s?){3,20}$/g;
```

Comment: 20 letras por palavra ou no total contabilizando também os espaços em branco?

Comment: Seriam 20 letras no total, contabilizando espaços também!

Comment: `/^([A-Za-z]\s?){3,20}$/g` você esqueceu/precisa de delimitar o começo com `^` no início da regex.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu super certo!